# What is the difference between baryonic and gravitational mass?

Tags: astrophysics, mass, neutron-stars

I was reading a webpage on [neutron stars](http://www.astro.umd.edu/~miller/nstar.html), and it mentioned that a neutron star's gravitational mass is about 20% lower than its baryonic mass due to gravitational redshift. I understand the basics of what the terms mean, but I do not see why gravitational redshifting would cause the gravitational mass to be reduced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In an oversimplified picture, imagine that a cloud of neutrons collapses gravitationally into a neutron star. You've lost a lot of gravitational potential energy, so by conservation of energy, the neutron star is now very hot. It radiates energy away and cools down. Because there has been a net loss of energy by radiation, the total mass-energy of the system has been decreased.

What's a little confusing about the presentation is that the author is using gravitational redshift as a measure of gravitational potential. They're equal, but to me it would be more conceptually transparent just to refer to gravitational potential.